# Netbeans, remove a control from a java form?

Tags: java, forms, netbeans, controls

I created a Java Form from the template that comes with netbeans. In the preview window for the Form I want to delete the blasted progress bar in the bottom. Everytime I right click and delete it, netbeans gives me an error and the file can't compile.

How do I delete this or any other control from a Java Form?

Comment: what is detailed error message ?

Comment: That's another problem, it's not actually giving me a specific error in the terminal or I would have Googled it. If I "run anyway" I get an uncompiled source error, otherwise it will say


/home/paul/.netbeans/6.8/var/cache/executor-snippets/run.xml:45:
Cancelled by user.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds)

Comment: Just so everyone knows, Click dragging the object off the form is not a work around. It still shows up after you recompile.

Comment: I think that you used the Desktop Application Project type. Just be aware that JSR 296 - The specification request that the project type is using is no longer being actively persued.

Answer (score 0):

I mean the problem " /home/paul/.netbeans/6.8/var/cache/executor-snippets/run.xml:45: Cancelled by user. BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds) – avatarmonkeykirby May 12 '11 at 9:41 "
For the second problem, I think you need to set the port number of the debugger. Click `Debug -> connect debugger`, then set the port number. I hope it works for you!

Comment: How does this relate to the question?

Comment: I mean the problem " /home/paul/.netbeans/6.8/var/cache/executor-snippets/run.xml:45: Cancelled by user. BUILD FAILED (total time: 3 seconds) –  avatarmonkeykirby May 12 '11 at 9:41 "